# TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand not list

Tags: python

I am working through Exercise 35 of Learn Python The Hard Way (LPTHW).

http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex35.html

I am struggling with one of the study drills of this exercise. Specifically "Add more to the game".

Here is the code that is returning the error:

```
def bear_room(): # A new encounter
    print "There is a bear here."
    print "The bear has a bunch of honey."
    print "The fat bear is in front of another door."
    print "How are you going to move the bear?"

    bear_moved = False 

while True: 
    next = str(raw_input("> "))

    if ["honey", "take"] in next: 
        dead("The bear peers at you for a moment, sizing you up, then claws your face off.")
    elif ["taunt", "lure", "yell", "scream", "shout"] in next:
        print "the bear has moved from the door. You can go through it now."
        bear_moved = True
    elif ["taunt", "lure", "yell", "scream", "shout"] in next and bear_moved: 
        dead("The bear gets pissed off and chews your leg off.")
    elif ["open", "door", "next", "through", "onward"] in next and bear_moved:
        gold_room()
    else:
        print "I got not idea what that means."
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's
`next in ["taunt", "lure", "yell", "scream", "shout"]`

not

`["taunt", "lure", "yell", "scream", "shout"] in next`

You have the test backwards.

Comment: Thanks very much tested and confirmed to work! They still seem the same to me, obviously they are not but ok!

Comment: Order matters in this case, 'the key is in the lock' is not the same as 'the lock is in the key'. Also, remember to mark the answer as correct.